# How to fetch the data from db in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY=array['0'] && CATEGORY=array['1'] && CATEGORY=array['2']';
```

my problem is array size was dependent sometimes it's count was 10 and some times it was 1.
if it was 10 i have to write the in query up to 10 times.
how to over come this.
finally i'm using codeigniter in that how to write this query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to format your query like this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where_in('CATEGORY', $array);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$cat_ids = implode(",",$array);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY in (".$cat_ids.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in CI

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to query like that

```
$this->db->where_in('CATEGORY', $array);
$executequery = $this->db->get('PRODUCTS');
```